# My question was based on experience but is closed under another reason

Tags: discussion, support

[my question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/667503/isnt-fedoras-dnf-a-failure) was based on experience but is closed under another reason:

> Closed. This question is opinion-based. It is not currently accepting answers.

Answer (score 9):

Your question asks, "Isn't Fedora's DNF a failure?".

A quote from [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask):

> To prevent your question from being flagged [and possibly removed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/helpcenter/deleted-questions), avoid asking subjective questions where …
>
> [...]
>
> - your question is just a rant in disguise: “______ sucks, am I right?”

Your question is a rant in disguise.  The community, therefore, voted to close it.

You *do* have some content that could be interesting to look further at (some issue with `dnf autoremove`?). Still, you provide no information about this that gives us any handle on the issue, like error messages, configuration details etc.

Your general sense of `dnf` being "slow" could also be presented more objectively and later possibly properly debugged.  However, there is no information to go on in the question.

The question as a whole is opinion-based, and when disregarding the rant, it is unclear (lacking enough details) and unfocused (more than a single issue).

Since the question has accumulated several downvotes, I would suggest asking new and separate questions about your issues with `dnf` if you want help resolving them.

Comment: the only thing that was a rant in disguise was in the comment ```> It is also like bad dream This is unix.stackexchange.com not psychology.stackexchange.com >```  I tested different distroes and came to a conclusion. If one can not understand the difference between criticism and rant. Well, the fall of Afghanistan isn't strange anymore (Because of Biden's decision and the closure of his critics).  **Fedora was a bad distro, based on experience**.

Comment: @user487583:  The difference between criticism and rant is irrelevant in this case.  The question, as written, still just asks for an opinion.

Comment: You continue to rant, opine and provide zero facts for your observations. I've been using Fedora since RedHat 5.0 (not RHEL, RedHat 5.0 which was released in the 90s) and `dnf` had been sort of slow before `libsolv` became a reality but nowadays `dnf` is lightning fast. Also your question contained outright falsehoods which I addressed in the comments.